# Use of socket io, nodejs + angular

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I am very new to socket Io, node and angular. I am currently working on namespace but I can't really connect to the other namespace. Could you please have a look at what am I doing wrong?

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

//namespace
var nsp = io.of('/nsp');


//when nsp connected
nsp.on('connection', (socket) =>{
       console.log('nsp connected');

 //when nsp disconnected
 nsp.on('disconnect', function(){
       console.log('nsp disconnected');
        });
    });

//route for nsp
app.get('/nsp', (req, res) => {
    res.send(console.log('Hello'));
});
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent{
  nsp;

  constructor() {
    this.nsp = io('http://localhost:3000/nsp');
  }
```

if a user access to 
http://localhost:3000/nsp then console should prints **nsp connected** that i have declared in `nsp.on('connection',(socket) =>{console.log('nsp connected');`

Comment: It looks like your route is set up on `/api/nsp` not `/nsp`

Comment: @jay can you tell me how can u done this socket code in angular and node bcoz i dont have any idea about this which site u refer and how to do socket programming in angular and node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your route is as */api/nsp* and not just */nsp* your code in **App.component.ts** should be as follow :

```
constructor() {
    this.nsp = io('http://localhost:3000/api/nsp');
  }
```

Comment: Silly me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please accept the answer so it will help others also

Comment: Man, turns out that was not my actual concern.. can you have a look at my code one more time?

Comment: Changing your question after an answer is not right bro.. if you have another question you have to ask again rather than completely changing the question

Comment: Sorry bro I will repost my quesion!